# Firebase auth or remote notifications error on iPad but not on iPhone

Tags: ios, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app uses Firebase Auth and remote notifications. On iPhone works well, but on iPad, appears this error:

*"Remote notification and background fetching need to be set up for the app. If app delegate swizzling is disabled, the APNs device token received by UIApplicationDelegate needs to be forwarded to FIRAuth's APNSToken property."*

Any ideas?